# Statements are not executed after getting Firefox driver

Tags: java, selenium

Following is my code

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("hi");
             WebDriver driver;
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        String actualTitle="";
actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println("hi");
System.out.println("ActualTitle is :" + actualTitle );
     //driver.close();

}
```

I have created it in simple Java application (with Selenium). The problem is that statements after getting driver are not executed. It should print hi and actual title but nothing is getting printed. Any idea why?

And following are all the libraries that I have added:

[image]

Comment: This looks like problem with FireFox, do you see FireFox opened when you execute the code?

Comment: wts the version of ur firefox ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, you are not waiting for the page to load before reading the title. Any web page takes some time to load. You need to wait till it is fully loaded and then proceed to do what you want. Put below line after you do a `driver.get('http://www.google.com')`:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The `30L` means that selenium will wait for a max 30 sec before throwing an exception.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Instead I used Chrome driver like this :  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/chromedriver.exe");
             WebDriver driver;
        driver = new  ChromeDriver();

Comment: You might have to clean --> build your project and then try running it again